# Sign conservation law in $n$-dimensions.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a scalar field continous at an interior point $a$ of set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $f(a)\not=0$, prove that  there is an $n-$ball $B(a)$ in which $f$ has the same  sign as $f(a)$.
How can I prove it?

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Let $f: S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ continous in $a\in int(S)$, so $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$$ Let $v(t)=a+tx$, note that $v$ is continuous function, also let $$\gamma: A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$\gamma(t):=f\circ v=f((v(t))$$Now, by hypothesis $f$ is continuous in $a$ and $f(a)\not=0$, so if $t=0$, we have $$\gamma(0)=f(a+0x)=f(a)\not=0$$Since that $f$ is continuous in $a$, so $\gamma$ is continuous in $0\in A$ and $\gamma(0)\not=0$. So using $\textbf{sign conservation law in one-dimensional}$  we have $$\exists \delta>0: \forall t \in (0-\delta,0+\delta) \cap A: \quad \gamma(t)\gamma(0)>0$$ Then $$\exists r>0: \forall x \in B(a,r)\cap S: f(a+xt)f(a)>0$$If $y=a+tx$, so $$\exists r'>0: \forall y\in B(a,r'): \quad f(y)f(a)>0$$
Finally, there is an $n-$ball $B(a)$ in which $f$ has the same  sign as $f(a)$.

Comment: Do you familiar definition of continuity that preimage of any open subset is open? The argument much simpler if we use this.

Comment: Yes, I know that. How would you prove it?

Comment: Since $P = \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus \{0\}$ is open subset contain $f(a)$, then $f^{-1}(P)$ is open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contain $a$. By definition of open subset there is a open ball contain in $f^{-1}(P)$ centered at $a$.

Comment: but, how do you guarantee that f has the same sign on the ball?

Comment: Oops. Choose $P=(0,\infty)$ instead for example if $f(a)$ positive. The ball will contained in $f^{-1}(P)$, which means $f(B_r(a)) \subseteq (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Maybe can you put it how "answer"? Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you mean. I don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111681/discussion-between-ramanujan-and-si-kucing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarizing some of the comments:

From continuity we know that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon
\end{align}
as long as $|x-a|<\delta$. Now, if $f(a)>0$, we can choose $\varepsilon<f(a)$ such that $f(a)\pm\varepsilon$ has the same sign as $f(a)$. Since there is a $\delta$ for this $\varepsilon$, you have found the ball around $a$.

Comment: You have a typo or missing word: Still has the same sign (which you assumed positive). In particular, choose any $\varepsilon<|f(a)|$. In fact, because of the inequality in the limit definition, taking $\varepsilon = |f(a)|$ work, even though your criterion fails there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. We can choose $\epsilon:=\frac{|f(a)|}{2}$ for to work in the prove.

Comment: I added this. Thank you for bringing it up